# Как создать pattern или path цепи вдоль линии

Tags: css, css3, svg

Мне необходимо создать  `pattern` цепи расположенный вдоль линии .
Я попытался создать `markers` в форме звена цепи, но возникли проблемы с  ориентацией маркеров вдоль `path`.

Есть ли альтернативный способ сделать это?
Если да, то каким должен быть мой подход?

Ожидаемый результат - что-то вроде этого:   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47828718/7394871)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47828718/7394871

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вдоль криволинейного пути можно направлять любое изображение с помощью команды:

```
<animateMotion  dur="4s" repeatCount="2">
                        <mpath xlink:href="#pathChain"/>
                </animateMotion>
```

Пример кода:

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="80 100 400 300">

<defs>
 <circle id="CirclePath" r="5" fill="red" />
</defs>
  <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>
 
<use  xlink:href="#CirclePath">
                <animateMotion
                  dur="4s"
                  repeatCount="indefinite">
                        <mpath xlink:href="#pathChain"/>
                </animateMotion>
                
        </use> 
</svg>
```

Но вдоль пути будет двигаться только один предмет, то есть одно звено цепи.  Чтобы разместить несколько десятков звеньев цепи, нужно будет десятки раз повторить эту команду и нет способов, как оптимизировать код. Плюс неизбежно появятся трудности с позиционированием и склейкой соседних звеньев.

Для размещения   текста вдоль криволинейного пути, в SVG существует другая команда - `<textPath>`

```html
<svg width="590" height="560" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
  <path id="MyPath" d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
  </defs>
  
    <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" textLength="400" lengthAdjust="spacing">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

В примере выше использована идея [из ответа Enso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851317/7394871) @Michael Mullany

Но цепочка выглядит совсем не так, как хотелось.

**А если заменить буквы на символы Юникода, которые более реалистично имитируют звенья цепи?**

Я остановился на варианте использования символа Юникода - *"Латинская маленькая буква на боку"* - `U+1D11` `&#7441;` и знак дефиса для соединения соседних звеньев цепи - `&#45;`

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="80 100 400 300">
 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>


<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>

</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

```
<tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan>    , где
```

`&#7441;` - символ Юникода, латинской `O` на боку.

dx="-15" - смещение этого символа влево.

**В дополнении пример анимации**

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="startOffset" values="1%;55%;1%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

**Update 16.12.2018 г.**

**Пример движения с паузами в начале и конце траектории при замедлении в центре.**

Такой алгоритм достигается повторением цифр в начале и конце атрибута 
анимации `values="1%;37%;55%;55%;1%;1%"`

Продолжительность всей анимации   `<animate  dur="12s"` делится поровну на количество позиций в  `values`
  Поэтому одна часть анимации будет `2s`, если позиции повторяются подряд `55%;55%`,- будет пауза в этом месте.

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>
<animate  dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="startOffset" values="1%;37%;55%;55%;1%;1%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

Источник ответа: [How can I draw a pattern along a stroke or a path in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860596/7394871) @Alexandr_TT

Связанный топик - [Использование символов Юникода в анимации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761188/28748)