# Использование символов Юникода в анимации

Tags: css, css3, svg

Вопрос возник по мотивам ответа: [Как создать `pattern` или `path` цепи вдоль линии.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/760120/28748)

Возникла идея,-  можно же использовать другие графические символы юникода для создания сюжетов, анимации. Коротенький код и картинка на экране, которую можно позиционировать, масштабировать, клонировать, стилизовать и анимировать!

Поиск символов на официальном сайте символов Юникода http://www.unicode.org/  энтузиазм поубавил. Всё так запутано на мой взгляд.

*Вопрос:*
Можно ли, как-то облегчить поиск нужного символа и показать на примерах основные моменты создания анимаций на основе символов Юникода.

Answer (score 5):

### Поиск требуемых символов

Нашел замечательный сервис по [подборке символов Юникода](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/transport-and-map-symbols/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно просто ввести в строке поиска название, например: "цепь", не нашлось, ввести английское слово "chain". И если есть такой символ, то будет показан не только он, но и другие тематически связанные символы.
Еще один плюс этого сервиса - он дает информацию, как будет выглядеть выбранный символ в вашем и в других браузерах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Создание анимации

Допустим нам необходимо создать анимацию движения пассажирского поезда.

Находим символ: 🚂 `&#128642;` Паровоз U+1F682  (Виден только в Firefox)

и символ 🚃 `&#128643;` Вагон U+1F683 (в Firefox выглядит более красочно),  в остальных браузерах, включая IE выглядит более скромно, но зато одинаково и можно стилизовать каждый вагончик, например: `fill="yellowgreen"` прямо внутри тега

```
<tspan fill="yellowgreen" dx="-6" > &#128643;</tspan>
```

`<tspan>` - является своеобразным контейнером для наших вагончиков. Внутрь него, как в случае с буквами, можно разместить от одного символа до нескольких. Но лучше по одному, так как есть возможность  настройки позиции символа, с помощью параметров `dx="x"` и `dy="y"`

Берем пример кода анимации из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/760120/28748) и подставляем наши символы.

**Пример кода ниже**

```html
   <svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="80 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/> 

 <text  font-size="24"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="green" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0"  > &#128642; </tspan> <tspan dx="-10" >  &#128643; </tspan><tspan  dx="-10" > &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-10"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-10" > &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-10" fill="purple"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan fill="crimson" dx="-10"> &#128643;</tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="2" attributeName="startOffset" values="0%;70%;0%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>   
  
</svg>
```

К сожалению браузерные войны продолжаются. Лучше всего этот пример выглядит в `Firefox`, но невозможно  стилизовать паровоз и вагоны. 
В `Chrome` паровоз не отображается, но зато вагончики выглядят одинаково во всех браузерах и даже в `IE` и их можно раскрасить в любой цвет.

Масштабировать элементы юникода очень легко, изменяя `font-size`, как у любого шрифта. К сожалению в svg не работает другая шрифтовая команда - [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing), но прижать элементы друг к другу или раздвинуть их, можно командами `dx`и `dy` тега `<tspan>`

Comment: Александр, привет. Ты как всегда  своей стихии...)) Приятно читать твои ответы и вопросы...

Comment: Alexandr_T, приглашение в чат  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat